# How do I route traffic through another server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, routing, linux-networking

I have two linux (Ubuntu) servers, A and B. Server A has access to the internet, B does not. The servers can communicate with each other via their respective (separate) default gateways.

I can access server B from the internet by port-forwarding via server A. As an example to allow ssh:

```
iptables --table nat --insert PREROUTING --protocol tcp --dport 61000 --jump DNAT --to-destination <B_IP>:22
```

**But how do I enable server B to access the internet through server A?** Server A is prepared to postroute with:

```
iptables --table nat --insert POSTROUTING --protocol tcp --jump MASQUERADE
```

Trying to replace the default gateway for server B with A's ip results in `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable` since it can no longer route to A. Servers A and B are the only I have access to. I cannot access their gateways.

Comment: How do A and B communicate with each other, are they on the same (probably private) network?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Yes, they both have a private address in the 10.0.0.0/8 block.

Comment: You really have not given enough info of the network setup for a "good" answer, but in addition to Masquerading a step 1 likely is setting the default gateway on (B) to the internal IP address of (A), or doing something equivalent.

Comment: @davidgo As I stated in my post I can't seem to replace the default gateway of B to be A's private address, to my understanding it is because B does not have direct access to A. If I perform `traceroute <B_IP>` it hops 4 times in the 10.0.0.0/8 block, with the first hop being A's default gateway and the last is <B_IP>. What other information could be helpful to give a useful answer?

Comment: As I suspected. You cannot change the default route on server B, since it is on another network segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default route must be on the same network segment (Ethernet broadcast domain) and it appears your two servers are connected through a router.

However, you can probably setup some sort of tunnel between the two. The simplest is an IPv4-over-IPv4 tunnel. For explanation's sake let `10.1.0.100` be server A address and `10.2.0.1` server's B. You can add to `/etc/network/interfaces` (or add a file in `/etc/network/interfaces.d`) on server B:

```
iface tun0 inet tunnel
    address 192.168.0.1
    local 10.2.0.1
    endpoint 10.1.0.100
    mode ipip
    netmask 24
    gateway 192.168.0.2
```

and on server A:

```
iface tun0 inet tunnel
    address 192.168.0.2
    local 10.1.0.100
    endpoint 10.2.0.1
    mode ipip
    netmask 24
```

That might be enough depending on your network topology and gateway configuration.

Explanation: This sets up a virtual interface that, instead of sending the IPv4 packets directly on the wire, wraps them into another IPv4 packet and sends them from `address` to `endpoint`.

You don't explain your network topology, but if A's gateway probably knows how to reach B, so `SNAT/MASQUERADE` may not be necessary (except if a firewall blocks incoming packets to B).

Comment: Thank you! Although I couldn't get your answer to work, it forced me to read and learn more about the basics of routing. For future reference, http://linux-ip.net/linux-ip/ was very well written and easy for me to understand with basic examples. My solution was to set up ipip tunnels and assign local addresses to the virtual interfaces (192.168.0.1 to A, and 192.168.0.2 to B). Then I replaced the default gateway of B to use A's new virtual address (192.168.0.1). I also had to make sure A was still reachable by adding a route to 10.0.0.0/8 through the old gateway.

Comment: I corrected the answer, following your comment.